# match just one row in two files and return the whole column from file 2

Tags: linux, file-management, bioinformatics

If I have two files

file1:

```
Reference Position
905894
1197693
3703749
92108275
114940633
114940633
```

file2:

```
Mapping  Reference Position Type    Length  Reference   Allele  Linkage Zygosity    Count
1 mapping   877831  SNV 1   T   C       Homozygous  48
1 mapping   883625  SNV 1   A   G       Homozygous  23
1 mapping   905894  SNV 1   C   T       Heterozygous    41
1 mapping   909768  SNV 1   A   G       Homozygous  85
1 mapping   1153944 SNV 1   T   G       Heterozygous    65
1 mapping   1197693 SNV 1   G   A       Heterozygous    23
1 mapping   1276973 SNV 1   G   C       Heterozygous    4
1 mapping   1276974 Insertion   4   -   ACAC        Heterozygous    52
1 mapping   1277533 SNV 1   T   C       Homozygous  73
```

I want the reference positions in both files to match and return the whole column in file 2 that matches with file 1.

Comment: do you mean column or row?

Comment: It's going to take a little work, but it may help to line up the data with the column headings.

Comment: i mean row i wrote the opp so value from file1 ex "905894" match the value in file2 in 2nd column and return the whole row as output i.e 1 mapping   905894  SNV 1   C   T       Heterozygous    41

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `egrep` should help. Try:

`grep -E '(905894|1197693|3703749|92108275|114940633)' file2`

This will check for an occurence of the pattern provided in `file1`. When testing it out, I got this for the results:

```
[rkahil@xxxxxx ~]$ grep -E '(905894|1197693|3703749|92108275|114940633)' file2
1 mapping   905894  SNV 1   C   T       Heterozygous    41
1 mapping   1197693 SNV 1   G   A       Heterozygous    23
```

Comment: what if i have a bigger row(more values) just mention the row 1 in file 1 to grep?

Comment: You would just add a pipe symbol in parenthesis and add the pattern to the regex

Comment: its taking too long to give the output file

Comment: What that is doing is grepping through file2. The results are dependant on how big file2 is.

Answer (score 0):

To match a number, you can use grep return a row:

```
$ grep 883625 file2
1 mapping   883625  SNV 1   A   G       Homozygous  23
```

if you want to output all the lines in `file2` which have numbers in `file1`:

```
$ grep -f file1 file2
Mapping  Reference Position Type    Length  Reference   Allele  Linkage Zygosity    Count
1 mapping   905894  SNV 1   C   T       Heterozygous    41
1 mapping   1197693 SNV 1   G   A       Heterozygous    23
```

i.e. the `-f` option of grep scans your `file1` and tries to find matches in `file2`. Here, also the header is matched by the first line in `file1`. From `man grep`:

```
-f FILE, --file=FILE
     Obtain  patterns  from  FILE,  one per line.  The empty file
     contains zero patterns, and therefore matches nothing.
```

Answer (score 0):

### Use `grep` reading patterns from file

We can use the whole lines in `file1` as fixed stings patterns - the option `-F` tells `grep` to not interpret the patterns as regexps.
Grep has an option `-f` to read patterns for a file, with one pattern in each line. That's just what we have, so the patterns can be directly read from the file.

```
$ grep -F -f file1 file2       
Mapping  Reference Position Type    Length  Reference   Allele  Linkage Zygosity    Count
1 mapping   905894  SNV 1   C   T       Heterozygous    41
1 mapping   1197693 SNV 1   G   A       Heterozygous    23
```

### Avoid matching substrings

The command above uses patterns from `file1`, like `905894` for example. If there would be a row in `file2` that has `9058940`, the `905894` would match, because it matches the first six characters. That's wrong. So we need to make it match only whole words. We could change the patterns to match word starts and ends, like `'\b905894\b'`, but `grep` has an option for this common case: `-w`:

```
grep -F -w -f file1 file2
```

### Exclude header

We do not want the headers, even though it's technically correct that they are shown, as the header `Reference Position` occurs in both files.

With `tail -n +2`, we pick the lines starting from the second, and use `-` as the file name to read the output of `tail` from stdin:

```
$ tail -n +2 file1 | grep -F -w -f - file2
1 mapping   905894  SNV 1   C   T       Heterozygous    41
1 mapping   1197693 SNV 1   G   A       Heterozygous    23
```

In bash, this does about the same:

```
grep -F -w -f <(tail -n +2 file1) file2
```